# How to check if the package exists from inside the annotation processor (in compile-time)?

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing

I'm building an Annotation Processor for Android (for the sake of future explanations, let's call it `TestProcessor`).

The plan is for the processor to operate in two modes:

- **`Mode 1`**: Generation of the code **`A`**
- **`Mode 2`**: Generation of the code **`A`** and **`B`**

---

**`Mode 2`** should be only selected if the additional (optional) package exists in the environment for which the processor generates code.

Is there a way to find out **in the Annotation Processor's `process` method** if the optional package exists?

---

***EDIT 1:***

Small clarification on the "(optional) package". By the additional package I mean a java package that **may** but does not have to exist in the project (that is using the processor). The optional package can for example represent the contents an external library. The external library can but does not have to be included in the project.

Let me just make a small example:

- Let's assume we have a (one-module) project `Sample`.
- `Sample` is using my `TestProcessor`.
- Let's take `Square's` `Picasso` as an example of an external library
- If `Sample` HAS `Square's` `Picasso` as one of its dependencies, `TestProcessor` operates in **`Mode 2`** and generates code `A` and `B`. In other words: if you can use classes from `com.square.picasso` (in `Sample`) without any problems, then processor should operate in **`Mode 2`**.
- If there is no `Square's` `Picasso` in `Sample's` dependencies, `TestProcessor` operates in **`Mode 1`** and generates only code `A`.

---

***EDIT 2:***

I thought of two workarounds for this problem:

1. Using two types of annotations for two `processor` **`Modes`** (example: `@DoStuffModeOne`, `@DoStuffModeTwo`)
2. Using a second type of annotation (that should be used for example on the `Application`) that triggers the usage of **`Mode 2`** (example: `@TriggerModeTwo`)

For my case the second workaround is much more preferable, but is still *much* worse than it would be if the `TestProcessor` itself could decide which **`Mode`** to choose.

Comment: What, exactly, is an "additional (optional) package"? Do you mean a Java package? If so, what does it mean for a Java package to exist? Do you mean that a directory exists for that Java package? Do you mean that a source file exists in that directory? I haven't written an annotation processor, and so I cannot help you directly, but editing your question to clarify what you are referring to might help others help you.

Comment: Sure, let me clarify that...

Comment: are you aiming for a specific package check?

Comment: Yes I am. Currently I want to check if `butterknife` exists in the project, but the question is more general.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to have different annotations for the different modes and let the annotation processor do what it does best (it also would be kind of unexpected behavior if after adding some 3rd party library referencing one of your "mode triggers" this would lead to different output, maybe even breaking the build)

Comment: The "different output" wouldn't be a problem. It wouldn't confuse or mislead user because if the optional package is not used, the additional code (code `B`) does not make any sense, more so would cause a build to fail (because of the missing references). As for the different types of annotations, that was one of the workarounds I was thinking about. Let me edit my question to include this and a second workaround that I was considering.

Comment: There is no such thing as the existence of a package. There is only existence or non-existence of classes or interfaces or resources within that package.

Comment: @EJP It was more of a simplification (you can see that in my example I'm referencing to "using classes from the package"). Maybe not the most "correct" simplification, I admit...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "an optional package" being present in the environment of the processor. Can that "optional package" mean a specific class in a package or any class which is part of a specific package? (`package.name.ClassName` vs `package.name.*` in terms of classname patterns?)
By environment, you mean the binary classpath of the compilation? Or the source to be processed by the annotation processor? Or maybe both? If you mean the binary classpath, is it enough for the package to be present there or you require that the source is actually referring to a class in that package?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete I think you should see the example I gave in my first edit to the question. That should explain most of your doubts. Summerizing: If it simplifies things, "a specific class in a package" is fine. That would give me enough information. Environment is the source to be processed by the annotation processor. The best thing would be (but I could probably work around it) if I could include those additional classes in compiler and still detect if they exist in the source to be processed.

Comment: If you mean 'optional class', *why not say so?* Fix your title and your question. Who knows, you might even get a better answer that way.

Comment: @BartoszLipinski does my answer below help you? Any feedback whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a check for one of the `ButterKnife` classes in the classpath of the application. Then perform your logic based on the check's result.

```
Class butterKnifeClass = null;
try {
    butterKnifeClass = Class.forName("butterknife.ButterKnife");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // no butterknife present
}
if (butterKnifeClass != null) {
    // blah... stuff with butterknife
}
```

Comment: The only issue is that it would only work if the `optional package` (`butterknife` in this example) is NOT present in the compiler. I know this requirement wasn't mentioned by me originally, so you're currently the best pretender to be granted the bounty :) Let me wait few more days to see if any more answers come up.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code to find out if a class is present in the annotation processing environment.

```
TypeElement typeElement = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils().
    getTypeElement("com.squareup.picasso.Picasso");
```

I didn't have success using the `Elements.getPackageElement()` method because it returned successfully for non-existent packages (at least under Eclipse), and running the  `PackageElement.getEnclosedElements()` method on packages created like this was empty even for non-empty packages. I'd suggest you go for a specific class in your package of interest as in my prior example because it worked as expected for existing type elements and returning `null` for non-existing types.

I currently didn't find an Annotation Processing API based method to decide whether the type element found in this way is based on a *source code file* on the source path of your project or a *binary class file* on the compilation classpath. There could be a method for this involving the `processingEnvironment.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, ...)` but, unfortunately is not portable, because `StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH` is not supported in Eclipse.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I need to check if it exists in the source code for which the annotation processing is being performed.

Comment: Does that mean that you need to support both JDK based annotation processing builds and Eclipse based builds too? JDK should work with the `processingEnvironment.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, ...)`. Eclipse could be made to work too, but it's a bit uglier.

Comment: Eclipse makes difference between a TypeElement that's based on a source file or a binary class file. It's not exposed by the Annotation Processing API, but you can easily fetch it by reflection after detecting that in fact the Eclipse compiler is running your processor. Or you could include the relevant Eclipse plugin API into your code and go with an explicit cast and decide from there if indeed is based on a java source file or a binary class. I know it's not the proper way to do it, but what can we do if Eclipse decided to deny getting a resource from the SOURCE_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution JBirdVegas suggested;  This function can be used to check **whether a package exists in the external libraries** at runtime.

```
public static boolean packageExists(String packagePath) {
  return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(packagePath) != null;
}
```

Usage :

```
packageExists("apackage/innerpackage")
```